# Is the phrase "the Italian for healthy taste" correct grammatically?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I found on a bean can the phrase "the Italian for healthy taste". I'm wondering if it's an English way to say or it's just a wrong sentence?

[image: A can of Gusto Sano chick peas with "The Italian for Healthy Taste" printed under the logo]

Comment: it kinda nonsensical, though typical of marketing-speak

Answer (score 8):

I found references online to a brand **Gusto Sano**, which is, literally, the Italian expression for 'healthy taste'.

Presumably you are puzzled by *the [language] for something*, a perfectly normal way of saying 'the word for that thing in that language'.

Comment: In your exact context - and indeed many others - the leading definite article would be entirely optional if you'd happened to phrase it as *"Gusto Sano" is [the] Italian for 'healthy taste'.* Personally, I wouldn't normally include that article, but arguably it helps with [the?!] parsing when included on a product label.

Comment: In a question I think many people would use the article: "What's the Italian for ....?" I would myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It appears to be a registered trademark, which could influence the choice to include the article. Everything gets a bit weird when lawyers are involved :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Compare to the tagline for Foster's: "*Australian for 'beer'*".  Of course, Australian isn't a language, and the name doesn't literally translate (and hardly anyone there but tourists actually drinks the stuff, though it is made there), but it's the same kind of sentence formation, but they omit the article before it, and it sounds much more natural than "*The Australian for 'beer'*" would.

Comment: I also want to say that the definite article sounds “wrong" in this context. It might not be ungrammatical, but I’ve never heard a native English speaker use this construction with a definite article.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Check out [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%27s+French+for%2CWhat%27s+the+French+for&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=7) for ***What's [the] French for...?*** with/without the article. There was an inexplicable "blip" a couple of decades ago, but the preference for *including* the article has been pretty consistent. Especially in the *British* corpus - and arguably we get first dibs on [the?!] "correct" usage here, seeing we're *closer* to France. (So maybe we get to ask that exact question more often, on day trips to Paris! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a rather confusing label at first glance.

It should be read:
*Gusto Sano - the Italian [phrase] for "healthy taste"*

In English it's common to say "X is [language] for Y", as in "*buenas noches* is Spanish for *good night*", so the above wording isn't exactly wrong, but broken up on the label that way, it's certainly difficult to understand.

Comment: It's a registered trademark, so it's probably not intended to be read literally. It's like "Shop smart, shop S-Mart".

Comment: Not at all confusing to a native speaker, especially in the UK where 'the [language] for Y' is perfectly idiomatic (see the discussion under my answer above).

Comment: @KateBunting I am a native English speaker. My point isn't about language but visual design -- splitting up the X and the explanation that it's "the [language] for Y" makes it confusing because it isn't visually obvious that "the Italian for..." part is referring back to the brand name, which is contained in an obvious logo.  When I first looked at the can, not being familiar with this brand, I couldn't figure out why it said that on the label. It took several seconds to realize it was talking about the phrase "Gusto Sano", and only because I already know those words in Italian.